# Can the sum of the individual breakers greatly exceed the main?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I have a 100amp subpanel in my garage that I wired with several high-capacity appliances, such as 50amp welder, 20amp compressor, 20amp AC, 30amp car charger, 30amp car lift, plus 3 15amp circuits for generic 110v outlets.  As long as I am aware that I shouldn't charge my car, run the AC, and weld at the same time, am I okay with this setup?

When it passed inspection my electrician mentioned off-hand that he was a little worried about load calcs, and he was glad it passed.  If the main breaker trips at 100amp, why was he worried?

Comment: It's not entirely against code; but an inspector wants to ensure that your electrical equipment can work reasonably. Sure everything can't go at once without tripping the breaker, but the goal is to try and not trip the breaker constantly with an average load. It depends on what is considered average. The electrician might think you'll run more average than you do and the inspector thinks you'll run less. - To shorten it, repeatedly tripping the breaker is still bad for the system and the goal is to be able to power a reasonable amount without doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no problem.  The Electrician may have been worried about the inspector failing the work after doing load calculations, but it doesn't sound like he did one.

As long as the installation is proper, there should be no problems.  You might trip the main if you run too much at the same time, but you're already aware of that limitation.